# DateTime Conversion in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, datetime

I'm trying to insert a datetime value to my database. I'm using entity framework with ASP.NET MVC 4 and SQL server.

```
using (dc = new GateEntities())
{     
   tblSite site = new tblSite();
   site.CalledInAt = DateTime.Parse("19/09/2013 00:29 AM", new CultureInfo("en- US", false));    
   dc.tblSites.Add(site);
   dc.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I try to save the data I get the error:

> "The value '19/09/2013 00:29 AM' is not valid for CalledInAt."

I also tried `Convert.ToDateTime()` but no use.

This works fine in my local machine. It's not working only on my shared hosting server.

Comment: Why don't you just make a `new DateTime`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130.aspx

Comment: Is the exception raised from DateTime.Parse(...) or from SaveChanges()

Comment: It's probably because of different culture settings on application and database.

Comment: @Alireza it occurs at SaveChanges()

Comment: try dc.tblSites.Count(p=>SqlFunctions.IsDate("19/09/2013 00:29 AM")); and compare it with dc.tblSites.Count() and report the result.

Comment: Is there a validation attribute on CalledInAt?

Comment: Just guessing, but you may try to set the DateTimeKind by calling `site.CalledInAt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(site.CalledInAt, DateTimeKind.Utc);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the culture in web.config and it started working.

```
 <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in the code you list.

The first (which I guess is an error introduced while typing the question) is that your CultureInfo is being set to `'en- US'` which should be `'en-US'`

The other is that US dates are formatted Month then Day and in your string that would make the date you are setting the 19th month of the year.

This code below works for your date value...

```
DateTime.Parse("09/19/2013 00:29 AM", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", false));
```

Comment: @chamara use `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` instead, you can specify whatever format you want to parse for the `DateTime` value.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is caused by EF's validation which happens in a culture that has a different date format than the string `19/09/2013 00:29 AM`.

When it comes to assigning values to entity properties from user input, the best approach is to make sure that you are independent of UI culture. This means that in the UI (probably a view model) you have to capture user input and convert it to a `DateTime` value. Then you just assign the `DateTime` value to `site.CalledInAt`.

Another option is to include the UI culture in the view model and use it to do the conversion in the controller.

Comment: hello! i need to save the datetime in dd/MM/yyyy format in the database. can you please give me an example of the second option?

Comment: You don't save datetimes in any format in the database, that's the point. You just store datetimes, and datetimes have no intrinsic format. Unless you store strings that represent datetimes, but that is something to avoid at any cost.

Comment: sorry i didn't get you.please bear with me since i'm new to entity framwork